# boost::any with limited type support

Tags: c++, c++11, types, dynamic-typing, boost-any

I wish to have a type that acts similarily to `boost::any` but with a more limited type set. Something like this:

```
limited_any<int,long,string> x; // x is like boost::any but is guaranteed to contain only an int, a long, or a string
```

How would you recommend implementing this? (Either on my own or using existing solutions)

Comment: You could look into how `boost::variant` does it.  While `boost::any` is a typesafe equivalent to C's `void*`, `boost::variant` more resembles C's `union`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/).

Comment: @tohava Note that there are a few differences.  The biggest implementation difference is that `any` is free-store based, while `variant` is automatic storage based.  (Plus, `variant` has a richer type-safe interface than `any`)